# mod_auth_cas redirects random requests to CAS login

Tags: javascript, apache2, cross-domain, cas, mod-auth

I'm using mod_auth_cas as authentication system on my applications but I have a problem, even when I'm already logged in to CAS and making AJAX requests to my server some requests are being redirected to CAS login page.
The problem is that CAS is on another origin so the requests which are not JSONP just fail.
Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We have just had the same problem. The solution is simple:
**Configure Apache to use MPM Prefork.**

The problem happens when Apache is configured to use MPM Worker. When many requests arrive simultaneously (i.e. 20 requests), some of them are randomly redirected to the SSO server.